# factorial program does not return prompt

Tags: shell, c

This program (`factorial.c`) is running but it does not return the prompt at the end, unless you hit enter:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int num, i, fact = 1;

  printf("Enter a number to know its factorial: ");
  scanf("%d",&num);

  for(i=num;i>0;i--){
    fact = fact * i;
  }

  printf("Factorial of %d! = %d",num,fact);

  return 0;
}
```

Compiling and running the program:

```
bash-4.2$ gcc factorial.c
bash-4.2$ ./a.out
Enter a number to know its factorial: 5
Factorial of 5! = 120bash-4.2$
```

After I hit enter:

```
bash-4.2$
```

Comment: This question is more likely to be answered on Stack-overflow than here.

Comment: Fix your formatting, please.

Comment: Notice: `120bash-4.2$`.  It printed the prompt at the end of the last line of output.  You didn't include a newline in your last call to `printf`.

Comment: It seems to me that the prompt is returned at the end, you just need to add a newline to your output: `printf("Factorial of %d! = %d\n"...)`

Comment: The prompt is visible in the output you show; there just isn't a newline before. What happens if you add a `\n` character at the end of your printf format string?

Answer (score 3):

This behaves identically to the `printf` that's included via the command line. It uses the same C libraries to implement as well. Note the behavior:

```
$ printf "Factorial of %d! = %d" 4 24
Factorial of 4! = 24$
```

You must include a literal newline (`\n`) to `printf` if you want it to display it like so:

```
$ printf "Factorial of %d! = %d\n" 4 24
Factorial of 4! = 24
$
```

Comment: can you please show me where to put the \n in the following line

Comment: printf("Factorial of %d! = %d",num,fact);

Comment: printf("Factorial of %d! = %d\n",num,fact);